# The number of permutation of 3 colors, one of which is red, out of a set of 7 colors, one of which is red, is:

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The number of permutation of 3 colors, one of which is red, out of a set of 7 colors, one of which is red, is:

A - 45

B- 90

C- 180

D- 210

Can anyone explain to me why the answer is B please?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the colour is red , so red can occupy any one of the 3 available positions.
There 6 remaining colors. So other place which red has not occupied cab be occupied in 6 ways.  Now there are 5 colors remaining. So the final position can be occupied in 5 ways.

So total number of permutations are
3×6×5=90.

Comment: Did you get it?

Comment: ok, got the first part but why did you only have 5 colors remaining? The total is 7 colors and subtract the red one, are we supposed to have 6 color remaining?

Comment: For second position red has been used so out of seven 1 is used so 6 remaining. Now for third position there are 5 remaining because out of 7 red is used and another (which can any out of6) is used for second position.

Comment: For example if second is yellow it then third cannot be red or yellow so there are 5 remaining.

Comment: Now you got it?

Comment: got it. thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Select two colours other than red.

$\dbinom{6}{2}$

Arrangements

$3!$

So, required ways is

$\dbinom{6}{2}3!$